# Opening PDF from http response (InputStream)

Tags: android

I'm nots sure if my question is correct. I'm kinda stuck here. I'm geting a response from server which returns InputStream - it's basically a pdf file

Do I have to write the stream to file, and store it temporarily on the device or can I open it directly somewhow?

Comment: If its a PDF you'll have to write it in a file and store it temporarily and then you can view the file. else you'll have to write a PDF parser yourself which is no mean feat.

Comment: you would go for storing it to the file correct?

Comment: Correct. I would store the file either in the SD card or in a temporary buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stored a temp file on SD, and then opened with PDF viewer, if there was one installed.